# Mathematica Save Directory

Tags: files-and-directories

*Mathematica* saves everything to `Documents`. I want it to save it into a folder `Documents/Mathematica`.

Comment: I think $UserDocumentsDirectory holds the location where it is storing your documents. You can, with great care and caution, change your init.m file for Mathematica to give a new value for that which will then be used each time you start Mathematica. Be very careful when changing init.m, you don't want to make a mistake and somehow corrupt Mathematica.

Comment: what is the deal with the phantom LaTeX!? It's breaking the rendering of the question!

Comment: I don't like having to bandy about this diamond, but: *unless you give a reasonable explanation for the useless $\LaTeX$, *kindly stop**.

Comment: Stack Exchange does not allow short questions. So I artificially make it longer. Why doesn't latex work for you?

Comment: …and you just didn't consider that you could try writing a better version of your question.

Comment: In my experience, Mathematica does *not* save everything in Documents. The Save As... dialog opens in the directory that you have used last. If you mean by "saving" using commands like 'Put' and 'Write' with file names without path specification, then your statement is true. You can either add the path to the filename (in the name string or preferably using `FileNameJoin`) or use `SetDirectory` to change the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SetDirectory`:

```
SetDirectory["yourdir"]
```

Comment: Will this persist between instances of mathematica? edit: apparently not.

Comment: @grdgfgr, that's what you use `init.m` for.